Examples of Complex Manifolds
I'm trying to learn about Complex Manifolds, and something that has proven a stumbling block is the paltry number of examples provided. The best of the book I found was Huybrechts Complex Geometry which includes most of the examples below but it still isn't enough. I still feel like I don't know what a typical or even a pathological complex manifold looks like. I want a bigger list in the sense that if I conjectured that every complex manifold has a certain property and you managed to check that it is true for every item of the list, you might start thinking the conjecture is true.
I would start the list as:

$\mathbb C^n$, the canonical complex manifold;

quotients by nice group actions such as tori $\mathbb C^n/\Lambda$ and the projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$;

the complex Lie groups $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$, $\text{SL}(n, \mathbb C)$, etc;

the simply connected Riemann surfaces given the uniformization theorem (the complex plane, the hyperbolic plane and the Riemann sphere) and Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ for $g\geq 1$;

preimages of regular values of holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C$;

products of odd dimensional spheres $S^{2p+1}\times S^{2q+1}$


...
What other commonly encountered complex manifolds are there? And what are the ways of constructing new complex manifolds?

Other books to consider: Morrow & Kodaira, Griffiths & Harris, Wells. Your list is missing all the smooth projective varieties, many of which are discussed in detail in — say — Griffiths & Harris.

Yes, understand submanifolds of projective space. One more nice pathological example is the Hopf surface.
